# Is there a "<code>" or "<pre>" window in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

I have just started using the editor and downloaded the "Full Package".

I want my users to be able to enter code into the editing window. Is there anything that makes this easy for them to do?  Any plug-in that I can use or is it part of the full package and I just missed it ?

**Update:**

I added to my config.js so it looks like this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.extraPlugins = 'insertpre';
};
```

When I check with fiddler the file is downloaded okay:

```
GET /Scripts/ckeditor/plugins/insertpre/lang/en.js?t=D6IE HTTP/1.1
```

But I don't see any icons to enable the pre.  I have a build-config.js file. Do I need to make changes there?

Answer (score 2):

yes there is a plugin for that.

check this link.http://ckeditor.com/addon/insertpre

download and configure it as given instruction on site.

Comment: Thanks - I followed the instructions and added it to my config.js file but I don't see any new icons to enter <pre> code. I will update my question to show more details.

Comment: no you should not add it there, this is the file, when ckeditor  builds. means when downloading ckedior, it gives u an option to customize plugins. so it is not required.you can check this also.http://ckeditor.com/addon/pbckcode

Comment: You said "no you should not add it there".  But where should I add it ? Thanks

Comment: it should be added in config.js file and it can be loaded on fly , mean when you initialize editor. if it is difficult to you then, please try to download ckeditor by customization. there is an option to attach many plugin by default. but keep in mind it work for 4.1,

Comment: You say it should be added in the config.js file but my post specifically says "I added to my config.js so it looks like this". I am confused :-(

Comment: check the link that is given in answer and check the compatibility given there.

Comment: Okay thanks. Do you mean to say the plugin is not compatable with the latest version of CKEditor? As you mentioned I tried to download it by customization. Then when the editor opens I get the message: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL ace.js:25 I am not sure what to do now :-(

Comment: If you are still stuck in this then you can opt for other plugin as "code " is good plugin and rated 4.

Comment: What do you mean "other plugin as "code " is good plugin".  I did a custom download and there's nothing called "code" in the list of available plugins? Please if possible can you give more details in your answers as I don't understand the English in what you are saying. Thanks very much.